# Bootstrap's responsiveness not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I recently developed a website using bootstrap 3 and it looked fine on my browser,i am using firefox and tried the responsive design layout in the developers tool and the website works fine all the nav-menus works great but when i uploded it for test and tried it with a mobile phone using multiple browsers but it doesnt look how it is suppose to look ,the nav-manus didnt shrink to the collapsible button  so does anyone seem to know the problem ?any comment is help full thanks. I know i am suppose to post some codes but the code is a lot to be posted.

Comment: not without the code

Comment: can you share code which you have used for mobile device...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this code in the head if you didn't

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: This solved the problem thanks...sorry for not providing enough info